# Can I use Python Scapy library to add protocols which are not listed in the output of ls() function?

Tags: python, scapy

Can we use the Python Scapy library to add the types of protocols which are not found in the output of **`ls()`** function?

For example the result of `ls()` does not contain the GSM SCCP protocol, but I want to add it so that I can manipulate GSM SCCP messages.

Can I do that? I was looking at [this tutorial guide](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html), and I have got the impression that I can add novel protocols.

The question is that can I even add protocols which are not in the ouput of `ls()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can! That's one of Scapy's purpose.

`ls()` only lists the protocols currently implemented in Scapy.